# Will this package cause performance issues?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, broadcast, stream-builder

*This question was first posted to [r/FlutterDev](https://reddit.com/r/flutterdev)*

I wrote a 2 class (+ some extensions) state management wrapper around the StreamBuilder + StreamController.broadcast(). I'm not sure if I'm overlooking some important performance details, but it seems to me this is sufficient code to update the UI wherever necessary, without the need for BuildContext.

Could you please tell me if I'm missing something? The package is [streamable_state](https://pub.dev/packages/streamable_state)